# How to extract and save the model from Callback history in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I have trained a autoencoder with Early stopping using different epochs but for a certain epoch using early stopping I am getting a minimum loss. How to access that model from that specific address and save it. Below is the picture for reference-
[image]

I want to access the model from the specified address and then save it.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what do you mean from that specific address? What is address here?

Comment: what's 0x7f325...? in this

Comment: You cannot access those addresses in python. Not sure what is the point here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you want to save the model at the time the training early stops.

Refer to:

https://keras.io/api/models/model_saving_apis/

https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/

A simple `model.save()` should work (you can do so after the `model.fit()`) or if you want to have checkpoints every time the loss reaches a minimum then use the `modelCheckpoint` callback.